# How do I set up a pair/array of strings for a Jenkins build parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I am currently trying to set up a Jenkins pipeline build that takes an array of string pairs as a build parameter.

The said parameters will be used to switch certain subdirectories of the working copy to specified branches, effectively granting Jenkins the ability to work with mixed branches: i.e. if `[{"A1", "A2"}, {"B1", "B2"}, {"C1", "C2"}]` is given as the parameter, Jenkins will switch the local subdirectory `A1` to the URL `"A2"`, local subdirectory `B1` to the URL `"B2"`, and so on.

Taking a list and switching branches for each pair can be simply done by a pipeline script; the problem is finding a way to actually pass an array of strings, or a pair of strings.

Initially I was trying to use the multi-line string parameter for the user to input the pairs one per each line, separated by a comma. However my PM insisted that I must not use this method for the input string being hard to read/type, so that's out of the question.

Searching for Jenkins plug-ins with the tag "Build Parameters" was fruitless as none of the plug-ins provided the functionality I am looking for.

Is there any way in Jenkins where you can set either:

- a build parameter comprised of two user-input strings, such as a key-value pair,
- or a build parameter that is a variable-length array of user-input strings, that you can add/delete to?

Or should I just create my own Jenkins plug-in to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) for this purpose.
Add an Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter named `PARAM` in your job, and provide this groovy script:

```
return """<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="border:none" class="jenkins-form-label" name="value" Value="A1" readonly size="40"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="jenkins-input" name="value" Value="A2" size="100"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="border:none" class="jenkins-form-label" name="value" Value="B1" readonly size="40"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="jenkins-input" name="value" Value="B2" size="100"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="border:none" class="jenkins-form-label" name="value" Value="C1" readonly size="40"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="jenkins-input" name="value" Value="C2" size="100"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>"""
```

Approve the script and select `Formatted HTML` in **Choice Type** dropdown.

In pipeline script you can use this param as `env.PARAM`, the value you will get is `A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,`.

Comment: This may be a viable option in various cases; is there any way to let the user also manipulate the length of the parameter list as well?

Comment: One way to do that is by introducing another variable named `NUM_OF_PARAMS` and reference this variable in the config of PARAM parameter. You can apply a for loop till the integer value of `NUM_OF_PARAMS` in groovy script to get that many input parameters.

Comment: Ah, that could definitely suffice for my case. Thank you for your kind advice; your answer is now marked as accepted.